# Are there fewer requirements for getting a Canadian tourist visa when you have a US tourist visa?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas, applications

A few weeks ago, I saw a list of requirements for the Canadian tourist visa, where it was specified that if you have a valid US tourist visa, you don't need to submit some documents like bank statements and company letter. Now I can't find this list anymore.

Did the rules change? Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: Is it this [statement on the Canadian Embassy in Austria web site](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/austria-autriche/visa.aspx?lang=eng): *As of November 1st, 2017, if you have travelled to Canada in the last ten (10) years or currently hold a valid United States non-immigrant visa and can provide proof (entry stamps in passport, proof of the valid visa), no proof of financial support is needed.* I don't find it on the gov't site www.cic.gc.ca site; it may be national-specific; I'd be cautious about not including documents.

Answer (score 1):

What we both referenced is the program known as CAN+ for visitors of some countries who have been to Canada in the last 10 years or who have a valid U.S. visa. When applying through CAN+, the applicant only needs to submit proof of travel to U.S. or Canada and can submit fewer proof of financial support. The program is only available at certain visa offices or for nationals or legal residents of certain countries.

There is no separate application form; rather

> [**How do I know that my application can be processed under CAN+? What supporting documents should I submit?**](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=877&top=16)
>
> [Visa application centres](http://www.vfsglobal.ca/canada/) will screen all applications for CAN+ eligibility. Applications that show that the applicant travelled to Canada in the last 10 years or holds a valid U.S. non-immigrant visa will be sent to the visa office for expedited processing.
>
> Check the [document checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) for full details of what you need to submit with your application.

As you found in Canada’s Singapore visa office, on page 1 of the document:

> **CAN+ Program: Proof of previous travel or valid USA visa**
>
> If you have travelled to Canada in the last ten (10) years or currently hold a valid United States of America non-immigrant visa, provide proof of this Canadian travel or valid USA visa (entry stamps in passport, proof of the valid visa).

In other examples, the CAN+ program is available to nationals in [Mexico](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/mexico-mexique/imm/pressrelease-communique-2014-05.aspx?lang=eng), and [India](https://www.canada.ca/en/news/archive/2014/07/can-program-facilitate-trade-travel-india.html). In [France, CAN+](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/france/CAN_program.aspx?lang=eng) has the requirements vary slightly:

> - Have previously been issued a Temporary Resident Visa to Canada in the last five years; and
> - Have had NO immigration infractions (for example: deportation, refused visa, inadmissibility…) in ANY country
> - Be a legal Resident (in other words to be  legally residing) in the country where they are living.

See also [Wiki: Visa Policy of Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Canada)